# How to enable responsiveness on fixed-width site built on Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, fixed-width

I have a problem with bootstrap. I needed a fixed-width layout, so i added div.wrap wrapper to whole page with width:1170px attribute and got what I want. But later I figured out that this trick disables responsive in Bootstrap.

Is it possible to built responsive website with fixed-width layout on Bootstrap? How do I enable responsive now?
Thank you.

Comment: Check the bootstrap documentation - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container - _"Use .container for a responsive fixed width container."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `max-width: 1170px;` instead of `width: 1170px`?

Comment: No problem, @Roman. You might want to up-vote the answer to mark it as the one that worked for you. This will help anyone else that has the same issue.